# Getting StackOverFlowError in Java

Tags: java, stack-overflow

This is program I am writing. I am getting a `StackOverFlowError` exception when I run it:

```
public class maininherit {

   maininherit h = new maininherit() {

        @Override
        public void mai() {
            System.out.print("inner");
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args){
       maininherit t=new maininherit();
       t.mai();
    }

    public void mai(){
       System.out.print("hellllll");
       h.mai();
    }
  }
```

Here I am getting `StackOverflowError`s only when I am using `maininherit` class as a reference in the inner class.  If I am using other classes I am not getting that error.  Can anyone clarify this to me?

Sorry i am thank full for your answers but i had a doubt i don't know whether reasonable or not only repetition of initializations can be possible only when i created instance in constructor of that same class know.then how it is possible to have multiple initializations?

Comment: Wow that's a very partcular class. You did it in a learning process?

Comment: yes...i am preparing to write scjp.by trying different ways to implement inner classes i came with this

Comment: ok you're trying to write stranger code as the one the guys from the scjp exam do ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
maininherit t=new maininherit();
```

Creates a new maininherit object (I'll call it `m0`), which has a field of the same type (I'll call that `m1`)

When m0 is created, m1 is initialized. m1 also has a field, so m2 is initialized. m2 also has a field so m3 is initialized etc.

This would go on forever if the `StackOverflowError` didn't oocur

Comment: ..yeah i understood what u said but when m0 is initialized u told m1 is initialized that can happend only when we are declaring m1 in constructor know?

Comment: @satheesh no, the compiler moves field initializations into the constructor (if you don't specify a constructor, the compiler creates one for you)

Comment: @satheesh yes, as I said: field initializations are copied into your constructor by the compiler. There's no way for you to stop that. Your design is flawed

Comment: okay sir i understood i thought if we are going to define constructor field intialization copying will be prevented

Answer (score 9):

Implementation of your inner class is just override part of maininherit class. So...
You init class maininherit then variable *h* were initialized. **New** operator were called and then... inner class init maininherit again and need to set h variable.

Your code is infinitive loop of initializations h variable.

Comment: +1 Yes you're right the problem comes in the init process of the class.

Comment: @satheesh, because in that case you don't create the same class instance recursively. If the `hello` class was creating more `hello` instances when initializing, then it would lead to the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is not with your `main` and `mai` functions, but with your initialization of the `maininherit h` member variable. The problem is that each instance of `maininherit` is creating a `maininherit` object (which in turn, creates  a `maininherit` object, etc.). Marking that as a `static` member will cause a single copy to be shared by all instances, which will solve this issue.

Comment: In other words: each time you create a `maininherit` object, you **also** create another `maininherit`.

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow error will occur whenever you try to create instance of same class as a member variable. So h instance is created infinite times and hence stackoverflow error came.

For e.g. the code you gave, even without inner class it will throw stackoverflow error

```
public class maininherit {

maininherit h=new maininherit();


public static void main(String[] args){
   maininherit t=new maininherit();
   t.mai();
 }

public void mai(){
    System.out.print("hellllll");
    h.mai();
}}
```

Avoid creating object of the class itself as a member or field